# php code appears on my Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: php

I'm using the php code below for my Wordpress website:

```
<?php

function cta_fixed() {
     echo do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="2893"][/et_pb_section]');
}

    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cta_fixed' );

    do_action( 'wp_footer' );

?>
```

It works as I wanted in the front end. But I also see

```
[et_pb_section global_module="2893"][/et_pb_section]
```

In my dashboard. How can I prevent this?

Regards,

Mark

Comment: You just `echo` the result and it prints it as it should. What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

You should only have add_action()

```
  function cta_fixed() {
 echo do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="2893"][/et_pb_section]');
   }

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cta_fixed' );
```